How to fetch documents from supabase where user id is NOT present in the array?
My supabase collection has a nullable column users. When it's not a null it is an array that holds uuids.

I am trying to get all the records where user id is not present in an array or if usersis NULL.
The issue I have is with getting records where user id is not in an array.
So what works for me is:
supabase.from.select(`*`).is("users", null)

What does not is if I use .or statement
supabase.from.select(`*`).or(`not(users.cs.{${userId$.get()}},users.is.null`))

I double checked that userId$.get() returns uuid, but even if I input user uuid directly in to the call like this: supabase.from.select(*).or(not(users.cs.{"4347c7ce-8827-4da0-a8c0-3021c95f5092"},users.is.null)) it is not going to work.
Every time I get an error: [Error: "failed to parse logic tree ((not(users.cs.{"4347c7ce-8827-4da0-a8c0-3021c95f5092"},users.is.null))"
I tried to swap places where I put users.is.null first cause I thought supabase will check if array is null first and than if it's not it will move on to checking if user id is part of an array.
I also check that the not() expression in or() is correct by replacing users.cs with another users.is.null just for testing purposes so it will look like this:
supabase.from.select(`*`).or(`users.is.null,users.is.null`)

And that works just fine.
So I guess the issue must be users.cs.{"4347c7ce-8827-4da0-a8c0-3021c95f5092"} but I don't know what I'm missing here.
Maybe my syntax is incorect, but I can't see it.
